# Is it possible to use SQLAlchemy on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, sqlalchemy

Trying to find out if it's possible to use SQLAlchemy on Heroku.  Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you try? What are you trying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The `DATABASE_URL` environment variable provided by heroku fits perfectly as argument for `create_engine`. Behind the scene, it's a postgresql database, which is perfectly handled by sqlalchemy.

The way to do it may vary depending on the framework you use, but there shouldn't be any difficulty.